# Meteor Subscriptions Selecting the Entire Set?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

I've defined a publication:

```
Meteor.publish('uninvited', function (courseId: string) {
    return Users.find({
        'profile.courses': {
            $ne: courseId
        }
    });
});
```

So, in when a subscriber subscribes to this, I expect `Users.find()` to return **only** users that are not enrolled in that particular course. So, on my client, when I write:

```
this.uninvitedSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe("uninvited", this.courseId).subscribe(() => {
            this.uninvited = Users.find().zone()});
```

I expect uninvited to contain only a subset of users, however, I'm getting the entire set of users regardless of whether or not they are enrolled in a particular course. I've made sure that my data is correct and that there are users enrolled in the course that I'm concerned with. I've also verified that this.courseId is working as expected. Is there an error with my code, or should I further look into my data to see if there's anything wrong with it?

**Note:
When I write this:

```
this.uninvitedSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe("uninvited", this.courseId).subscribe(() => {
    this.uninvited = Users.find({
        'profile.courses': {}
    }).zone();
});
```

With this, it works as expected! Why? The difference is that my query now contains 'profile.courses': {}.

Comment: Just in case it's relevant, my sample data right now consists of one user that is in every course, and 5 other users that are in none of them.

Comment: Have you removed the autopublish package?

Comment: Additionaly, regarding your **Note : filtering in your subscription with that query also fits your publication pattern so it's not a valid test imho, you could create users that are in some courses but not this particular one?

Comment: Yeah, I have no autopublish package. Also, yeah I've created users like that, and it still doesn't work.